# "The specified view is invalid" in call to LimitedWebPartManager.AddWebPart in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

This code used to work in WSS 3.0 / MOSS 2007 in FeatureReceiver.FeatureActivated:

```
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager limitedWebPartManager = Site.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared)) {
    ListViewWebPart listViewWebPart = new ListViewWebPart {
        Title = title,
        ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper(),
        ViewGuid = view.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper()
    };
    limitedWebPartManager.AddWebPart(listViewWebPart, zone, position);
}
```

I'm trying to convert to SharePoint 2010 and it now fails with:

```
System.ArgumentException: The specified view is invalid.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewCollection.get_Item(Guid guid)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart.EnsureListAndView(Boolean requireFullBlownViewSchema)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart.get_AppropriateBaseViewId()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.AddWebPartInternal(SPSupersetWebPart superset, Boolean throwIfLocked)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.AddWebPartInternal(WebPart webPart, String zoneId, Int32 zoneIndex, Boolean throwIfLocked)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.AddWebPart(WebPart webPart, String zoneId, Int32 zoneIndex)
```

Interestingly enough when I run it from a unit test it works, it only fails in FeatureActivated.  When I debug with Reflector it is failing on this line:

```
this.view = this.list.LightweightViews[new Guid(this.ViewGuid)];
```

list.LightweightViews only returns one view, the default view, even though list.Views returns all of them.  When running from a unit test LightweightViews returns all of my views.  I have no idea what LightweightViews is supposed to mean and I'm running out of ideas.  Anyone else got any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make it work, just do the following:

- Do not set the viewguid property of the listviewwebpart object  (leave it blank)
- call the AddWebpart method

It will generate a new viewguid associated to a new hidden view.
Then if you want to customize this view, retrieve it from the list and customize it.

Comment: This alternative also worked for me: 1. Do not set ViewGuid, 2. AddWebPart, 3. set ViewGuid, 4. SaveChanges

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully no one ever has this problem or even sees this question.  In the unfortunate event you get the same problem I have no specific solution.  It eventually just started to work for me (8 hour later).  I can tell you what I did right before it started working and hopefully it will help:

I went in through the UI and set the view that I was trying to set the list view web part to as the default view.  I believe that's what fixed it and I have no idea why.

Some other notes on the problem:

- I create all my lists and views through code
- RunWithElevatedPrivileges did not help
- Instantiating a new SPWeb in feature activated did not help
- Setting ListViewXml = view.HtmlSchemaXml instead of setting ViewGuid made it not crash but the view was wrong when this code executed in FeatureActivated but correct when executed in a unit test.

Best I can do, sorry.  If you're having this problem, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/5d87c0cc-2a8d-48ea-87e9-454ce440db0e/) and [this](http://ketulpatel.wordpress.com/2008/06/25/programatically-working-with-listviewwebpart-using-non-default-view/) articles I found even more easiest solution.
When you add listviewwebpart to an any page, webpart automatically creates new hidden view in list, which is associated with this webpart (you can check it in SharePoint Manager).
When you switch view for listviewwebpart throw UI, it simply get copy of fields from selected view and push it in his hidden view.

All you need is get this view by ID, add\remove necessary fields and update view. Something like this:

```
            var wpMngr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(workspaceWeb.Url + "/default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared);
            var attendeeListViewWebPart =
                (ListViewWebPart)wpMngr.WebParts.Cast<WebPart>().FirstOrDefault(w => w.Title == Lists.AttendeesList);
            var list = workspaceWeb.Lists[Lists.AttendeesList];
            var view = list.Views.Cast<SPView>().FirstOrDefault(w => w.ID.ToString("B").Equals(attendeeListViewWebPart.ViewGuid, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            view.ViewFields.DeleteAll();
            view.ViewFields.Add...
            view.Update();
```

According to articles, you cann't update ViewGuid property for listviewwebpart.

Answer (score 1):

I have been fighting with this today also.

For some odd reasons the code that you provided works for some cases but not in others.

I haven't had time to investigate more about that but what I can say is that if you are willing to use the XsltListViewWebPart (which is the replacement of the ListViewWebPart in SharePoint 2010), you will get rid of this annoying "bug".

I have just tested in myself.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error with an `XsltListViewWebPart`:

```
 Exception: System.ArgumentException: The specified view is invalid.
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewCollection.get_Item(Guid guid)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetView(Guid viewGuid)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetView(String viewGuid)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BaseXsltListWebPart.EnsureView()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BaseXsltListWebPart.get_AppropriateBaseViewId()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.AddWebPartInternal(SPSupersetWebPart superset, Boolean throwIfLocked)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.AddWebPartInternal(WebPart webPart, String zoneId, Int32 zoneIndex, Boolean throwIfLocked)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.AddWebPart(WebPart webPart, String zoneId, Int32 zoneIndex)
```

Since [SPList.GetView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getview.aspx) is a public method, I tried it in Powershell using the Guid from my new view. It worked fine.

I figured out that the problem was the context. I had been creating my view right before the [ViewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.viewguid.aspx) assignment. When I moved the creation of my view outside of the [SPLimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.aspx), the code ran without any errors:

```
SPView view = CreateHiddenView(list);
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
{
    try
    {
        XsltListViewWebPart webpart = new XsltListViewWebPart();
        webpart.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
        webpart.TitleUrl = list.DefaultViewUrl;
        webpart.WebId = list.ParentWeb.ID;
        webpart.Title = list.Title;
        webpart.ViewGuid = view.ID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
        manager.AddWebPart(webpart, "Right", 1);
    }
    finally
    {
        manager.Web.Dispose();
    }
}
```